# Error 503 while connecting to cloud Postgres (hosted on GCP) using gcloud/google sql proxy

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, cloud-sql-proxy

I have cloud postgres setup on GCP with public IP enabled. Previously, I have been able to connect via google sql proxy but now I am getting following error:

> errors parsing config:
> googleapi: Error 503: Policy checks are unavailable., backendError

If I try to list sql instances using `gcloud sql instances list` that also throws same error. As per https://status.cloud.google.com/ there is no disruption in any services.
Postgres server is running with no issues and other tools accessing the db directly are also running, the issue with accessing the db locally using google cloud proxy.

Comment: There is already a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/1248) raised for similar issue. You can follow up over there for more updates.